# Bracha on Blowing Shofar the whole month

Tags: elul, shofar, blessing

Why is there no Bracha made on the Blowing of Shofar in Elul, like there is a bracha when one reads the Meggilah on Purim and lights candles on Chanukah (which are also Rabbinic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Nois Hadeshe** says it is because the blowing the whole month of Elul is partially a preparation for the blowing on Rosh Hashanah, and as the Ran says in Kesubos as to why we don’t make a Bracha on Kiddushin but do on Nissuin because Kiddushin is a preparatory step to the consimation of the Marrige through Nissuin, so to the Blowing in Elul is a preparatory step to the ultimate blowing of the Shofar on Rosh Hashnah itself and Hence blowing the Shofar the whole month of Elul requires no Bracha.

Answer (score 8):

The Megillah and the Chanuka candles are [Rabbinical Mitzvot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitzvah#Rabbinical_mitzvot), while blowing Shofar in Elul is merely an Ashkenzic custom (minhag), not a Mitzvah (see Rama on [Orach Chaim 581:1](http://www.shulchanarach.com/ch/SAch581c.htm)). There's all kinds of discussion about which Mitzvot get a blessing and which don't, but in general, minhagim don't get blessings.

Comment: Could be, but if so, it's presumably an even later minhag than the Ashkenazi one, since the Mechaber doesn't mention it.

Comment: @YS: different Sephardim do different things with Shofar. At one shul I've been to, we don't blow the shofar at all during Elul, at another we blow before *teanu v'teatru* in Kaddish at the end of selichot, at a third someone blows during the 13 middot in selichot and also before *teanu v'teatru*.

Comment: Chanoch or anyone else aware of sefardic Minhagim do you know the reasons?